# ASP.NET Use String Resource on OnClientClick JS function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my file resource I have a string like that:

```
<data name="JJDC.Text" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>eg</value>
  </data>
```

And I want use that string in my java script function OnClientClick

I already tried like this:

```
OnClientClick="return confirDelete( <% (String)GetLocalResourceObject("JJDC.Text")%> );"
```

But when I run the page give me an error:

```
The server tags can not contain constructions <% ...%>.
```

Somebody know how I can solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Because onClientClick is ran and parsed on the server. Just delete the `<%`

Comment: Ok, but give me that error now: `The tag server has an incorrect format.`

Comment: @youarebannedfromStackoverf because you are nesting same quote marks. change one pair to single quotes: `'`

Comment: Ok, I tried like that `OnClientClick="return confirDelete((String)GetLocalResourceObject('JJDC.Text'));"` and like that `OnClientClick='return confirDelete((String)GetLocalResourceObject("JJDC.Text"));'` but the 'OnClientClick' dont fire.

Comment: first make sure that you are calling the correct function. you are calling `confirDelete()` which is very likely a misspelled. you sure you didnt leave out the `m` by mistake?

Comment: Im calling the right function becouse for testing I tried `OnClientClick="return confirDelete('some string');"` and it works.

Comment: Nobody know how I can solve my problem? or I cant do that.